# A Fine Chain of Acronyms

Tags: wordplay

Consider the following set of 25 commonly-used acronyms

```
AMEX   PETA   CC     CCG    COBOL
DJIA   FLOPS  NAACP  ESL    SIAM
ASCII  FEDEX  VHS    GIF    SPCA
OEIS   BBC    FBI    HELOC  GPA
FICO   BBB    SVGA   MMORPG NBC
```

When expanded, these acronyms form a chain where each acronym definition shares exactly one word in common with the acronym that precedes it (note that articles such as "of", "the", "in", etc. do not count for matching purposes).

For example, consider the set of acronyms

```
NASA   DEA    ISS    FDA    IPCC
```

These can be chained together as follows:

```
IPCC :            International Panel on Climate Change
ISS  :            International Space Station
NASA : National Aeronautics and Space Administration
FDA  :                  Food and Drug Administration
DEA  :                           Drug Enforcement Agency
```

where the word linking each pair of adjacent definitions is aligned for clarity.

Some of the acronyms have more than one popular definition. The puzzle may be trickier than it seems!

**Can you chain all 25 acronyms together?**

*Puzzlers are encouraged to place answers in spoiler blocks to avoid inadvertently spoiling the fun for other readers.*

Comment: FLOPS doesnt produce any five star result in the site provided by you, not as if the entire question is wrong

Comment: @skv: Oop. I guess that one's only four stars. I'll amend the hint.

Comment: oh my god the most obvious solution is not even an option (and no other five star options) for FBI

Comment: @skv: It is in there, but it has zero stars for some reason. I'm just going to delete the hint altogether. I admittedly didn't look some of these acronyms up because, as you say, they have singularly obvious definitions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Image Version

> [image]

Text Version

> ```
>   OEIS    :                                                                             Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences
>   MMORPG  :                                                       Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game 
>   CCG     :                                                                                Collectible Card Game
>   CC      :                                                                                     Credit Card
>   HELOC   :                                                                 Home Equity Line of Credit
>   VHS     :                                                           Video Home System
>   SVGA    :                                                     Super Video                   Graphics Array
>   GIF     :                                                                                   Graphics   Interchange Format
>   ASCII   :                                                       American Standard Code for Information Interchange
>   AMEX    :                                                       American Express
>   FEDEX   :                                                       Federal  Express
>   FBI     :                                                       Federal         Bureau of Investigation
>   BBB     :                                                       Better Business Bureau 
>   COBOL   :                                                       Common Business Oriented             Language
>   ESL     :                                                                        English as a Second Language 
>   FLOPS   :                                                       Floating Point Operations Per Second
>   GPA     :                                                          Grade Point         Average
>   DJIA    :                                                       Dow Jones   Industrial Average
>   SIAM    :                                                       Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics
>   SPCA    :                                                       Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals
>   PETA    :                                                       People for the Ethical Treatment of      Animals
>  NAACP   : National Association for the Advancement of Colored    People
>  NBC     : National Broadcasting Company 
>  BBC     : British  Broadcasting Corporation
>  FICO    : Fair Isaac            Corporation
> ```

Just the ordering (in reading order)

> ```
> OEIS  MMORPG  CCG     CC      HELOC
>
> VHS   SVGA    GIF     ASCII   AMEX
>
> FEDEX FBI     BBB     COBOL   ESL
>
> FLOPS GPA     DJIA    SIAM    SPCA
>
> PETA  NAACP   NBC     BBC     FICO
> ```

Comment: Nice. I've been staring at two chains forever, but kept missing the GPA and FLOPS link.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at the page 100 times to see if someone already did it, kinda rush of blood

Comment: You even have the side-by-side word alignment with highlighting. Well done. :D

Comment: @COTO I had three or four instances where I gave an answer and then someone improved and literally stole my votes :P so this time I wanted to be caurtious

Comment: That's not the usual expansion of [SVGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_video_graphics_array) (although the normal expansion fits in the same place).

Comment: And actually, your expansion of SVGA doesn't fit the "*exactly* one word in common with the acronym that precedes it" requirement; it shares *two* words with VHS.

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree this fits better, I have edited the answer, but was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I never downvoted your answer.